# How to set the connection string from app.config please

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, console-application

I have done till this and i don't know how to call the connection string into my console application from `app.config`

```
<add name="VirgoPlaza" 
     connectionString="Data Source=JEAN-DANIEL\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=VirgoPlaza;Integrated Security=True"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Can someone help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First add reference to System.Configuration. In Solution explorer, right click on References, Add References.

Add reference to `System.Configuration` Manager.

[image]

Then access the connection string like:

```
var connectionStrings = System.Configuration
                            .ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings;
var yourConnectionString = connectionStrings["VirgoPlaza"];
```

Assuming you have stored connection string in `App.Config` like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <clear />
    <add name="VirgoPlaza" connectionString="Data Source=JEAN-DANIEL\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=VirgoPlaza;Integrated Security=True"
            providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

VB.Net equivalent would be:

```
Dim Cons As String = System.Configuration
                        .ConfigurationManager
                        .ConnectionStrings("VirgoPlaz").ConnectionString
```

You may see: [Connection Strings and Configuration Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254494%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Dim Cons As String = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["VirgoPlaz"] i'm having this error identified expected

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that you have your connection string defined inside this block of you app.config

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="VirgoPlaza" 
         connectionString="Data Source=JEAN-DANIEL\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=VirgoPlaza;Integrated Security=True"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/> 
</connectionStrings>
```

If this is the case then you retrieve the string from the app.config using

```
Dim cnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("VirgoPlaza").ConnectionString
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick cheat is use your server explorer to connect, and then copy the connection string from there. Alternatively just use the new entity framework and you can do it via a wizard as well.

EDIT: Ok, it seems you have the connection string now - however does this mean that you cant connect, could never connect or does it mean you are just stuck making it work in general?

Comment: i want to connect it by configuration manager but i can't find this option

Comment: Can you access the database using your current account via MSSQL Enterprise manager? If yes, then you have access. If no, then that's the issue. We can take it step by step.

Comment: i can access my database if i'm using it like that   Dim con1 As SqlConnection
        connetionString = "Data Source=JEAN-DANIEL\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=VirgoPlaza;Integrated Security=True"
        con1 = New SqlConnection(connetionString) but me i want to use the configuration manager so that when i have to change the place the database i can change it at only one place

Comment: Please see the answer (after edit) posted by Habib, this is the correct approach to read from the config.